# Is there a way to get list of loaded properties file in SpringBoot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file, wiremock, spring-boot-2

I'm facing an issue on only one platform when I'm trying to execute `mvn clean install`. As part of the build we compile multiple component and last we execute functional testing using wiremock. It is supposed to pick specific configuration from function testing profile and default properties should be picked from application.properties file. But for some reason same code isn't able to find the properties mentioned in these file. So, just wondering if somehow, if I can get the list of properties files being loaded during wiremock ? This will give some clue on why isn't expected properties files are being picked ?

All properties files are located inside :

```
src/main/resources
```

And, following from test class.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SampleFTConfiguration.class)
public class SampleControllerTest{
//test method
}

@ComponentScan("com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ft")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class  SampleFTConfiguration{


}
```

**Note :** I'm not expecting anyone to fix the issue, all I wanted to know, if we can get the name of loaded property files ?

Comment: Please add a code of your test, at least the annotations you're using in the test as well as the exact location of `application.properties` file. Without the code we can only speculate

Comment: You can get these details in log file/console. At server start up, all the details about configuration files being loaded are logged in log file/console.

Comment: @pratap Nope, we don't get file name in log/console

Comment: If you enable the DEBUG log, it should show the properties file loaded. I just created sample spring boot application and started with DEBUG logging, here is what I see in logs
```2021-03-23 11:53:17.157 DEBUG 16544 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfigurationProperties] ```

Answer (score 4):

After searching and trying out for a while, looks like `ConfigurableEnvironment` is what you're trying to find.

The code is pretty simple. However I think it's better to debug and check the `configurableEnvironment` value directly, so you can adjust the code to your needs (remove filter name, etc).

```
  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment;

  @Test
  public void getProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> mapOfProperties = configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources()
        .stream()
        .filter(propertySource -> propertySource.getName()
            .contains("application-test.properties"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(PropertySource::getName, PropertySource::getSource));
    mapOfProperties.values()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

the code will printed out

> {properties-one=value-for-properties-one,
> properties-two=value-for-properties-two}

with my application-test.properties value

```
properties-one=value-for-properties-one
properties-two=value-for-properties-two
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html

Answer (score 4):

To troubleshoot context configuration on app startup (for those who don't have an access to app sources) you can add

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot.context.config: trace
```

to your application.yml to get filenames:

```
2022-10-26 13:29:45.977 TRACE [,,] 16522 --- [main] o.s.b.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders   : Loading file [config/application-app.
yml] using loader org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader
2022-10-26 13:29:45.977 TRACE [,,] 16522 --- [main] o.s.b.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders   : Loading file [config/application-ppe.
yml] using loader org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader
```

Adding `org.springframework.boot.context.properties: trace` doesn't help much though. Some user-defined properties get logged, however others don't.

Comment: In my opinion, this solution answers the title question _Is there a way to get list of loaded properties file in SpringBoot application?_ best.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, following the test definition please make sure that:

1. You should run the test with spring runner (spring extension if you're on JUnit5). So you should place the annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` (or `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)` for junit 5)
2. The property source you're using is `application-test.properties`. You've said that the properties file is located in `src/main/resources` but the file name probably implies that it should reside in `src/test/resources`

Comment: Sorry, `application-test.properties` is inside `src/test/resources`. But, even I add any properties inside that file.. it doesn't picked up inside application. I do not want to make any changes to the code, because I know there is no issue with code. It is something to with platform where for some reason correct properties files are not getting loaded.

Comment: So are you using SpringRunner/SpringExtension? Without it the whole spring infrastructure won't start

Comment: I guess it should be @ExtendWith and not @Extend**s**With